# do not delete a file created by root user in the other users folder

Tags: linux, unix

I have a user called "sam" and the home directory of sam is /home/sam

Now as a root user i have to keep some files in /home/sam/Desktop directory . and sam should have only read and execute permission he should not delete that file.

not the desktop file will be a soft link of /usr/share/application

steps i have tried :

log in as root 
cd /home/sam/Desktop
echo "test not delete file" > /usr/share/application/abc.txt
ln -s /usr/share/application/abc.txt /home/sam/Desktop/abc.txt
exit
log in as sam
rm /home/sam/Desktop/abc.txt 
Do you want to delete write protected file? y
delete success

now how can i prevent it?

Comment: Have you tried 'chmod 444 /home/sam/Desktop/abc.txt' ?

Comment: @BZ yes i have tried all permissions types ? even i did 000 now the user sam is not able to read the file but still he is able to delete it. The problem is he has the Desktop directory full permission because he can keep create and delete his own files in the same directory . I just want to make sure that root user created file is not deleted

Comment: As far as I'm aware - if he owns the directory, he's always going to be able to do that.  You'd have to have root own the directory and remove his write permissions on the directory to achieve that.  What are you trying to achieve with this? Just accidentally prevent the user from deleting it?

Comment: Ok appears I am wrong - look at http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/tag/immutable-bit  and http://www.adminarticles.com/file-attributes/

Comment: @BZ chattr +i and chattr -i works but it is not supported in the symbolic link is there any other way ?

Comment: Can you do it on a hard link?

Answer (score 0):

Make the file immuteable : chattr +i /home/sam/Desktop/abc.txt